# How to test download process of xlsx/csv and other files using JMeter?

Tags: download, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

1. I have created one test plan

[image]

2. Thread group with one user

[image]

3. HTTP Request

[image]

4. Added HTTPS Script recorder and select thread to record

[image]

5. View Result tree added

[image]

6. Save Response to a file added

[image]

I have saved the test plan by doing the required steps / process which is of downloading different documents using one user.
The recorded script is with 1 user and I am rerunning with 50 users using   jmeter -n -t D:\Jmeter\DownloadFinal21Sept.jmx -l D:\Jmeter\ReportLog\result21SeptPDFinal.csv  -e -o D:\Jmeter\HTMLReport\Report21SeptPDFinal.

My queries are.

1. When I am using save response to the file then it is saving as .unknown whereas my downloaded files are .xlsx and .csv how to get default file format while saving it.?
2. Is it OK to use same credentials to use for 50 or 100 users as I have only one test credentials?
3. How to exclude check_user_activity and Success.txt from these reports.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. JMeter looks at [Content-Type response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) and if it is missing or cannot be mapped to the known file type, you can specify extension yourself and tick `Don't add suffix` box
2. It's better to have different credentials for different users but if for some reason you cannot get more - it should be okayish for file downloads testing
3. You can exclude "unwanted" results by using [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/))

In addition:

- You don't need to have HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder once you finished recording, it doesn't add any value but consumes valuable resources
- The same applies to [Listeners](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/), if you want to test download file progress and not interested in the file itself (i.e. you don't want to check contents of the file(s) you should rather remove all of them, especially View Results Tree one which is the most resource intensive

Comment: It looks fine to me. Well I have one query. One of my scenario is where I click 'Export to Excel' and 'Export to CSV'. Where can I checked how much time taken by the process from clicking these buttons to file exported to excel and gets downloaded on my system. Thanks.

Comment: JMeter doesn't "click" any buttons, it executes associated HTTP requests and measures time taken, given you properly simulate those HTTP requests you should have the timings already

Comment: Ya, I know that but problem I am facing is like below. I have a date filter and if I apply that for range of 1 week it exports the data to excel quickly but if the filter range of a year it has around 5 lacs rows. When I click export to excel it keeps spinning circle for more than 10 mins and finally without exporting it throws an error: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset. How to resolve this issue.?